# Not able to assign command line to variables arguments in Go

Tags: go, command-line-interface

Package used: `gopkg.in/urfave/cli.v1`

Code Snippet:

```
app.Action = func(c *cli.Context) error {

    author := "anonymous"
    filename := "Image"
    if c.NArg() > 0 {
        author = c.Args().Get(1)
        filename = c.Args().Get(2)
    }
}
```

I call a function which uses author and filename after the if statement but the result is that author and filename have their initial values(anonymous and Image) and not the ones from the command line arguments using the function as shown above.

I am fairly new to go and looked into the documentation of the package and cannot find a solution.

And if i do this:

```
author:=c.Args().Get(1)
filename:=c.Args().Get(2)
```

then the function returns blank strings and they get initialized to both variables

and the command I am giving is something like this:

```
terminal -q "hi" -a "Eklavya" -f "Eklavya"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is a bit incomplete, but you have probably defined the flags `q`, `a` and `f`.

c.Args().Get() works only on args that are not passed as a flag. e.g. the call

```
terminal hi Eklavya Eklavya
```

has the args 0, 1 and 2 defined.

To access the flags other funcs have to be used. The following change works:

```
app.Action = func(c *cli.Context) error {

    author := "anonymous"
    filename := "Image"
    if len(c.GlobalFlagNames()) > 0 {
        author = c.String("a")
        filename = c.String("f")
    }
}
```